# Unmounting dev/sda1 and downloading Ubuntu.iso problem

Tags: windows-7, unmount

I am installing windows7 over ubuntu and i created bootable Windows USB, when i click install windows it says:

> "Windows Setup Cannot find a location to store temporary installation
>   files. To install Windows, make sure that a partition on your boot
>   disk has at least 686 megabytes (MB) of free space."

I knew  it was because my hard drive is formatted as an ext4 and i must delete the partition and create a new ntfs one. But when i tried to do this, it says i have to unmount `/dev/sda1` manually. Then i also tried to unmount it through sudo command in terminal like `sudo umount /dev/sda1` and also `sudo umount -f dev/sda1` but it didn't work, the response was

```
device is busy. in some cases useful info about processes that use the device is found by lsof(08) or fuser(1)
```

So i have to make live USB and use gparted, But everytime i download the ubuntu.iso file with size 982mb, it'll say downloading complete even if it has only downloaded 200mb file. why this happened? the internet connection is stable and i tried it thrice. same thing "downloading complete" but it will never completed to its 982mb size.

What else should i do? Please help me fix this problem, i want to get rid from ubuntu and install windows. Please, Thank You.

Comment: Hey edward :) Thank you for helping me. Thank you very much. Now i am using windows8 actually. Again, Thank you so much :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you dont have any data on hard drive(backup to some other place like external harddrive) before you follow this method:

- I suggest to make boot-able DVD of windows first(you can buy a cheap DVD of 4.4GB from nearest store). [link on how to burn DVD with ISO here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu)
- You can try downloading Ubuntu ISO using transmission .i.e. torrent [link here](https://kickass.so/ubuntu-14-04-lts-desktop-64bit-iso-t9007063.html)
- make bootable pendrive using "UnetbootIN" software from your present Ubuntu. burn the Ubuntu ISO to a pendrive. and boot into it.
- After booting(now you are in live booted ubuntu not the installed one thats already on your PC), install Gparted and delete the whole harddrive and format it into NTFS. and shutdown the live session
- now boot in to DVD on which windows in burned. Done. from there you can start installing it.

*this time you wont get any error since your harddrive is NTFS.*

---

if you dont have any data on harddrive, you can delete all partitions at the time of installation.

How to delete partition at the time of windows intallation ?
select the partition then you will see `drive options(Advanced)` click on it and then click `delete`. do this for all partitions.
after this you will get only one partition, click on it and click `new` and click `next` to proceed with the installation

Comment: Thank you very much. I already created Live Ubuntu USB and i am trying right now. this site is my reference http://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation did he say was correct?                                                        If ever this one won't work. I will do your suggestion. Thank you very much.

Comment: @rhein this method show method for ubuntu. you want it for windows right ?

Comment: yeah right. But they say i have to unmount dev/sda1 manually. since it didn't work after how many tries, i had to make Live USB to make partition. so that i can proceed to windows7 installation.

Comment: ok. thank you. i have Live USB. can i use that to your method? same process?

Comment: I am just booting the UBUNTU.ISO right now. should i select first the Erase disk and Install ubuntu?

Comment: i already on your profile now. and already add you on my friends

Comment: yes edward! i am now using windows8. i dont like ubuntu. why?

Comment: @rhein i am fine. please remove all comments that are not technical.if you want to talk to me please come google plus chat. dont comment here :)